# How to annotate \hline entries with increasing count of hlines?

Tags: tables, annotations

I want to annotate hlines with numbers by their count -- I want to have the increasing count number on the left side of hline or right side.

**How can I annotate hline in LaTeX?**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ l l }
\hline%_{1}
1 & 2\\
\hline%_{2} 
3 & 3\\
\hline%_{3} How to annotate hlines?
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the definition of `\hline` from source2e and modified it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}

\newcounter{mycount}

\makeatletter
\def\hline{\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi% from source2e
  \stepcounter{mycount}\llap{\scriptsize\raisebox{-.75ex}[0pt][0pt]{\themycount}\hspace{.2em}}% added
  \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet\reserved@a\@xhline}% from source2e
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ l l }
\hline%_{1}
1 & 2\\
\hline%_{2} 
3 & 3\\
\hline%_{3} How to annotate hlines?
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]